# How can I save dynamic value in form

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller

I have form in laravel framework, and i want to save the value of the user input in order to use it in other textbox at the same form.
This is my Controller code:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    { 
$clientnames = Customer::where('payeee' , $request->payeee)->get('client_name');
```

but `$request->payee` doesn't return the value input of the user in the textbox.
how can i do it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it payee or payeee ?

Comment: Do you want to save, one input from `$request` for two property of customers that have that input?